# Android app crashing on restart

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I faithfully followed the guidelines here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html. I was surprised to find how easy it was to handle configuration changes using RetainedFragment. Everything works properly in normal flow of events. But there is a glitch. If I *minimize* the app and start it after a long time it crashes with the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main^M                                                                               E/AndroidRuntime( 5734): Process: net.citibuzz.app.scool, PID: 5734^M                                                
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.citibuzz.app.scool/net.citibuzz.app.scool.MapActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment net.citibuzz.app.scool.RetainedFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public^M
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)^M      
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)^M       
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)^M                  
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)^M            
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)^M                            
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)^M                                         
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)^M                       
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)^M                            
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)^M                                
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)^M         
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)^M                    
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)^M                                       
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment net.citibuzz.app.scool.RetainedFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public^M
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:413)^M                  
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)^M               
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1790)^M
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)^M     
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:97)^M    
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at net.citibuzz.app.scool.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:134)^M               
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)^M                          
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)^M     
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)^M      
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        ... 11 more^M                                                                            
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class net.citibuzz.app.scool.RetainedFragment; no empty constructor^M 
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)^M                                  
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)^M                                    
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)^M                  
E/AndroidRuntime( 5734):        ... 19 more^M
```

Apparently the system ran out of resources, killed the activity instance and then tried to recreate it on restart. This is a bit confusing for me. Looks like the system is handing two cases differently : one where it destroys activity due to configuration change and another when it destroys it due to resource crunch. I reckon this must be a common problem. How do I handle this ?

I am happy to provide code snippets if required , but as I said at the beginning I have followed Google's sample code to the T.

Edit:
OK, I realise I did make some changes of my own. I added a constructor :-(

```
public class RetainedFragment extends Fragment {

    // data object we want to retain
    private MapState data;
    private Context mContext;

    public RetainedFragment(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    // this method is only called once for this fragment
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // retain this fragment
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void setData(MapState data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MapState getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class net.citibuzz.app.scool.RetainedFragment;
```

You cant have a custom constructor within the fragment that it need to call its empty constructor, if it is not define then that exception will appear

here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) about it:

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor.
>   The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, 
>   in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this 
>   constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not
>   available,     a runtime exception will occur in some cases during
>   state restore.

By the way you can call the reference to context from the fragment by calling `getActivity();` to call the activity's context

If you want to instantiate your fragment then you need to create a static method that will return the reference of the newly created fragment

```
public static RetainedFragment newInstance(int index) {
    RetainedFragment f = new RetainedFragment();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

Comment: I was using the context to start a service .. So I guess I can use getActivity() for that.

Comment: @everydayapps yes you can.. because it is a context thus you can call start service on it

Comment: From the docs: "However, be careful to call getActivity() only when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not yet attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle, getActivity() will return null." onAttach() is called immediately after adding fragment, so I wonder what's the point of this reminder?

Comment: @everydayapps that is just a precaution that you always call your getActivity() after it is attached in the fragment, I recommend calling it in oncreateView method so 100% the getActivity() wont return null